# Find the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> a. $1+2i$
>
> b. $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$
>
> c. $1+\sqrt{2i}$

So I'm not sure how to do this. I would think I would do soemthing like $a=1+2i\rightarrow \frac{a-1}{2}=i \rightarrow (\frac{a-1}{2})^2+1=0$ but this doesn't seem like the right polynomial? Do I need to solve more or take a different approach? I know I want to find a "root."

I have continued on and tried to solve $1+\sqrt{2i}\rightarrow (x-1)^2=-1\cdot 2\rightarrow (x-1)^2+2=0\rightarrow x^2-2x+3$. Does this seem right?

And for $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ I got $x^4-16x^2+4$

Comment: "but this doesn't seem like the right polynomial?" why not? Maybe you want to distribute it out and multiply by 4?

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{2i}$ or $\sqrt{2}\cdot i$?

Comment: @Levent it is $\sqrt {2i}$

Comment: Part (c) is ambiguous.  Do we mean the square root of $2i$ in the first quadrant?  The third quadrant?  Both?  If we encompass both roots the result is a quartic equation, but this factors into two quadratics where one is solved by $1+$ the first quadrant square root of $2i$ and the other is solved by $1+$ the third quadrant square root of $2i$.

Comment: Are you sure? Because $\sqrt{2i}$ is not well-defined unless you already chose a branch.

Comment: I apologize I do not know any specifications on $\sqrt {2i}$. It is possible it may be $\sqrt {2} \cdot i$ but it does not look like it

Comment: Well ,usually in Galois Theory ,  over fields $F$, by an element $\sqrt{a}$ they mean an element $b$ in some extension of $F$ such that it is a root of the polynomial $x^{2}-a\in F[x]$ . So it is unlikely that they mean $\sqrt{2i}$ . Also $\sqrt{2i}$ has $2$ values namely $(1+i)$ and $(1-i)$ which will have different minimal polynomials both of degree $2$ obviously. Now it's upto you to choose which one do you want.